# selenium stop after input

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Python and Selenium coding, but I think I figured it out, tryed to build some exmaples for myself to learn from them, I got 2 questions,
First of all for some reason my code is stopping after my Input it does not going for the yalla() Function for some reason,

```
yallaurl = str(input('Your URL + ' + ""))
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(yallaurl)
browser.maximize_window()
yalla()
```

Other then this the other Question is about `browser.find_element_by_xpath` so After I go to an html file and click Copy xpath I am getting something like this:

```
/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table[4]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

So how is the line of code is working? is this legit?

```
def yalla():
        sleep(2)
    count = len(browser.find_elements_by_class_name('flyingCart'))
    email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table[4]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')
    for x in range(2, count):
        itemdesc[x] = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[x]/td[2]/a[1]/text()")
        priceper[x] = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[x]/td[5]/text()")
        amount[x] = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[x]/td[6]")
    browser.navigate().to('https://www.greeninvoice.co.il/app/documents/new#type=100')
    checklogininvoice()
```

Comment: What is the code in your 'yalla' function?

Comment: edited and added the yalla code, I doesnt think its inside the code, the problem is with the Pyton Because I tried to use print function after the browser is open but it didnt printed it in pyCharm...

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code will run just fine and is legit but not recommended.
As described, the absolute path works fine, but would break if the HTML was changed only slightly

Reference: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this code is confusing:

```
yallaurl = str(input('Your URL + ' + ""))
```

This is essentially equavilent to:

```
yallaurl = input('Your URL: ')
```

---

Yes, this code is correct:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table[4]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) for proper usage.
Here is the suggested use of this method:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table[4]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')
```

This code will return an object of the element you have selected. To print the HTML of the element itself, this should work:

```
print(element.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

For further information on page objects, please refer to [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html) page of the docs.

---

Since you have not provided the code for your 'yalla' function, it is hard to diagnose the problem there.

Comment: Then Why my code isnt going for the "yalla()" function, its stop directly after going to the URL, now I tried to write after it print("test" and it didnt showed at the console for some reason..